# Shortest path navigation across a grid using Best First Search

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, search

The code below is an implementation of the Best First Search algorithm for navigation of the shortest path across a 2D NxN matrix. As a heuristic for the search I use the standard distance formula. The matrix is generated from a text file passed in as a command line argument,where the first line is the size `N` of and each subsequent line represents a row. For example,

```
5
.+..g
.....
.....
.+...
i+...
```

The walls are represented as `+` and both `i` and `g` represent the start and goal positions respectively. Navigation can only be done in four directions, up, down, left, and right. I first parse the file and create a matrix of `Node` objects

```
import java.util.*;

public class Node {

    double cost;
    int type;
    int x;
    int y;
    ArrayList<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
    Node parent = null;
    boolean inPath = false;


    public Node(int x, int y, int type) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getX() { return this.x; }

    public void setX(int n) { this.x = n; }

    public int getY() { return this.y; }

    public void setY(int n) { this.y = n; }

    public double getCost() { return this.cost; }

    public void setCost(double n) { this.cost= n; }

    public void setType(int n) { this.type = n; }

    public int getType() { return this.type; }

    public void addNeighbor(Node n) {
        if(n.getType() != 3) {//check for not adding walls as neighbor=
            neighbors.add(n);
        }
    }
    public boolean isEqual(Node n2)
    {
        if(this.type == n2.getType()) { return true; }

        else return false;
    }
    public ArrayList<Node> getNeighbors() { return neighbors; }

    public Node getParent(){ return parent; }

    public void setParent(Node n) { parent = n; }

    public boolean getPath(){ return inPath; }
    public void setPath(){ inPath = true; }

}
```

to represent the `+` walls, `i` the initial position, `g` the goal position, and `.` the open spots.

```
import java.io.*;

public class fileParser {

    File inFile = null;
    int gridSize;
    int lineCount;
    Node[][] grid;
    Node initial;
    Node goal;

    public fileParser(String[] input) {
        if (0 < input.length) {
            inFile = new File(input[0]);
        }
        else {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void parse() throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
        String line;
        gridSize = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        grid = new Node[gridSize][gridSize];

        /*Create integer matrix for the given input. Nodes are given integer values corresponding to types*/
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                if(line.charAt(i) == '.') {
                    grid[lineCount][i] = new Node(lineCount, i, 0);//open
                }
                else if(line.charAt(i) == '+') {
                    grid[lineCount][i] = new Node(lineCount, i, 3);//wall
                }
                else if(line.charAt(i) == 'i') {
                    Node temp = new Node(lineCount, i, 1);//initial
                    grid[lineCount][i] = temp;
                    initial = temp;
                }
                else if(line.charAt(i) == 'g') {
                    Node temp = new Node(lineCount, i, 2);//goal
                    grid[lineCount][i] = temp;
                    goal = temp;
                }
            }
            lineCount++;
        }
        br.close();

        for(int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
                buildNeighbors(grid[i][j], i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    /*For each node that is not a wall represented as a 3, the corresponding up, down, left, and right neighbors will be
    added to a list*/
    public void buildNeighbors(Node n, int row, int col) {
        if(n.getType() != 3) {
            if(row == 0) {//Check for edge cases where neighbor amount will vary
                if(col == 0) {
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row + 1][col]);
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col + 1]);
                }
                else if(col == gridSize - 1){
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row + 1][col]);
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col - 1]);
                }
                else{
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row + 1][col]);
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col + 1]);
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col - 1]);
                }
            }
            else if(row == gridSize - 1) {
                if(col == gridSize - 1){
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row - 1][col]);
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col - 1]);
                }
                else if(col == 0){
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row - 1][col]);
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col + 1]);
                }
                else{
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row - 1][col]);
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col - 1]);
                    n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col + 1]);
                }
            }
            else if(col == 0) {
                n.addNeighbor(grid[row + 1][col]);
                n.addNeighbor(grid[row - 1][col]);
                n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col + 1]);
            }
            else if(col == gridSize - 1) {
                n.addNeighbor(grid[row + 1][col]);
                n.addNeighbor(grid[row - 1][col]);
                n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col - 1]);
            }
            else{
                n.addNeighbor(grid[row + 1][col]);
                n.addNeighbor(grid[row - 1][col]);
                n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col - 1]);
                n.addNeighbor(grid[row][col + 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    public Node getInitial() { return initial; }

    public Node getGoal(){ return goal; }

    public Node[][] getGrid(){ return grid; }
}
```

Once I have the matrix properly parsed, I pass in the `Node initial`, `Node goal`, and `Node[][] grid` to the actual `Strategy` class to implement the search.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Strategy {

    Node initial;
    Node goal;
    Node[][] grid;
    ArrayList<Node> closed = new ArrayList<>();
    nodeComparator nc = new nodeComparator();
    PriorityQueue<Node> open = new PriorityQueue<>(nc);
    boolean pathFound = false;

    public Strategy(Node initial, Node goal, Node[][] grid) {
        this.initial = initial;
        this.goal = goal;
        this.grid = grid;
        open.add(initial);
    }

    public void evaluate(Node current){
        current.setCost(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((current.getX() - goal.getX()),2) + Math.pow((current.getY() - goal.getY()),2)));
    }

    public void getSuccessors(Node n) {
        for (Node neighbor : n.getNeighbors()) {//evaluate cost of all neighbors, set their parent, and add them to the open list
            if(!open.contains(neighbor) && !closed.contains(neighbor)) {
                evaluate(neighbor);
                open.add(neighbor);
                neighbor.setParent(n);
            }
        }
    }

    public void getPath(Node n) {
        Node current = n;
        while(current.getType() != 1) {//backtrack through parents and use boolean marker to indicate path before reaching the initial node
            current.setPath();
            current = current.getParent();
        }
    }

    public void printGrid() {
        if(!pathFound) {
            System.out.println("No path found");
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
                    if (grid[i][j].getType() == 0) {
                        if (grid[i][j].getPath()) {//boolean tracker of what nodes are in the path
                            System.out.print("o ");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(". ");
                        }
                    } else if (grid[i][j].getType() == 1) {//initial
                        System.out.print("i ");
                    } else if (grid[i][j].getType() == 2) {//goal
                        System.out.print("g ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("+ ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void search() {
        while(!open.isEmpty()) {
            Node current = open.poll();
            closed.add(current);
            if(goal.isEqual(current)) {
                pathFound = true;
                getPath(current);
            }
            else {
                getSuccessors(current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The search evaluates the cost of each node by a calculating the Euclidean distance of the current `Node` to the goal.  Therefore an override was created for the `PriorityQueue` to properly sort the `Node` objects added.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

    public class nodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Node n1, Node n2)
        {
            return Double.compare(n1.getCost(), n2.getCost());
        }

    }
```

In order to run the search I pass in the command line argument into the `fileParser` object and subsequently call `Strategy search` and `print` the finalized grid with the path represented by the character `o`. For example, the output to the initial example listed is

```
. + . o g 
. + o o . 
o o o . . 
o + . . . 
i + . . .
```

The calls are made in the `main` as such,

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        fileParser fp = new fileParser(args);

        try {
            fp.parse();

            System.out.println("The shortest path to the goal is: ");
            System.out.println("");
            Strategy strat = new Strategy(fp.getInitial(), fp.getGoal(), fp.getGrid());
            strat.search();
            strat.printGrid();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate feedback regarding the performance and efficiency of the algorithm and areas where I have not provided adequate or proper implementation of it.

Answer (score 2):

### High-level reusable or purpose-built?

You wrote `Strategy` like a high-level, all purpose Dijkstra Pathfinder (works on nodes, which can be arbitrarily far, but your grid only allows 4-connected neighbours), which even uses an external Comparator for increased versatility.

You wrote `Node` like generic graph representation (it has a `List` of neighbours etc. but your grid only allows 4).

*However* `Strategy` uses intimate knowledge of Node: it knows it's in a grid. But `Strategy` does not need the `grid` to solve the problem (it uses `getNeighbours()`), it only needs it for *printing* the map... Which a `Strategy` shouldn't know how to do!

In the other hand you allow arbitrary distance in `evaluate()` function, but it only ever return `1`...

Right now it's all entangled.

**You need to decide what you want:**

- Make a more integrated and efficient solution which leverages the knowlegdge of the grid structure
- Make a more high-level solver which offloads intimate logic to its Node function. With the right hooks, this can stil be made quite efficient (leaving the door open for high-level optimization like switching to A-start without even altering the underlying application at all), but above all, *reusable*

---

Since this is Code Review, I can weigh in and say: you will want the latter, and split `Strategy` further away from `Node` class. I think you need a `Node` abstract class for the `Strategy`, and `GridNode` class for your grid application.

**Tip**: *Use* Java's package. Put `Strategy` in its own package like `algo.pathfinding`. Add an abstract `Node` class to that package, make it completely unaware of its grid structure. Then gather the grid-related stuff in its own separate package like `game.grid`. Using this, it'll be much easier to pull off a well-designed API.

---

### Remove the printing from the Strategy

It has nothing to do there. Let `Strategy` return a `List<Node>` as path, then pass that path with the grid to a `PathPrinter` class.

---

### Performance

- Drop the `sqrt`. If you override Node's distance function using GridNode, you can (and should) use manahttan. If you *know* the ceels are adjasent, return always 1.
- Use `switch` when checking cell contents: this is faster, and less error-prone.

---

### Ease of use

- Store the grid as a 2d array of enums. USing enums is  more powerful than String, char or ints, and the switch is more powerful (IDE auto-checks missing cases etc.)